# How to loop through BsonArray to convert into double type list?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am receiving `BsonArray` form db. 
When I am trying to iterate over this `BsonArray` like this

```
Console.WriteLine(data["avgResponseTimes"].GetType());
foreach(var singleRecord in data["avgResponseTimes"]){
   chatResponses.Add(Convert.ToDouble(singleRecord));
}
Console.WriteLine("each list average -- " + chatResponses.Average());
```

So it throws an error like this

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type 'BsonValue' because 'BsonValue' doesn't contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

But when i console the `type` of `data["avgResponseTimes"]` so it says `MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray` but it's not allowing me to iterate over this list of BsonArray.  I want to convert this `BsonArray` to the `double` type list to get the average of the list. How can I do that in c#(asp.net core 2.2)?

Comment: You will need to cast it first.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is a strongly typed and statically typed (i.e. types should agree at build time, not just run time) language.

While you know that `data["avgResponseTimes"]` returns a `BsonArray`, it's actually exposed as its base type: `BsonValue`. It isn't possible for C# to predict that `data["avgResponseTimes"]` will be a `BsonArray` (as opposed to, say, a `BsonObject`), so it has to only consider the methods and properties available in the base type (`BsonValue`). `BsonValue` doesn't define `GetEnumerator()` therefore you can't use it with `foreach`.

You can either check if `data["avgResponseTimes"]` is a `BsonArray` and extract the value using pattern matching:

```
if (data["avgResponseTimes"] is BsonArray responseTimes)
```

Or you can cast it if you're sure it will always be a BsonArray:

```
var responseTimes = (BsonArray)data["avgResponseTimes"]; // explicit
var responseTimes = data["avgResponseTimes"] as BsonArray; // implicit
```

Note that the above implicit cast will return `null` if `data["avgResponseTimes"] isn't a`BsonArray`.

Assuming "avgResponseTimes" is an array of `double` from the database, you might be able to get away with using LINQ rather than your `foreach` loop:

```
var responseTimes = (BsonArray)data["avgResponseTimes"];
chatResponses.AddRange(responseTimes.Select(t => t.AsDouble));
```